# Accidentally Cloned Repo into my repo

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo into my repo on accident, and commited/pushed it without realizing.  And now my github shows an extra 800+ commits that dont relate to my projects from this other repo I had cloned.  Is there anyway to remove all of these extra commits? I already deleted the directories that i had cloned.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you do this clone operation? Something like `git clone <url>` while in your repo wouldn't add any commits to your repo. It would just create a folder in there with a different repo in it. If you added and committed the folder, it would just add one more commit to your repo.

Comment: Maybe i did a pull and not a clone then.  I can't remember.

Comment: That sounds more likely. I'll add an answer that might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the history (e.g. `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`) and find the last commit before all of those new commits entered the picture. Armed with that hash you can just do `git reset --hard <hash>` (where `<hash>` is the hash of that last, good commit you found) to move your current branch back to that point. NOTE: if you have uncommitted changes in your working directory, they will be overwritten by this hard reset. After that, the newer commits will no longer fall inside the ancestry of the branch, and will disappear from view. They'll still be there in the objects folder, though, if you realize you need them. You'll have to force push this with `git push --force`. Note: This might disrupt anyone who's cloned or pulled from you recently and has started erroneously working on these wrong commits you added.

Comment: Will I lose my new commits since that `<hash>` commit though? I commited a few things and pushed them since then.

Comment: Yes, you would lose those. However, you could cherry-pick them down onto the old, good commit, which is like copying them one at a time. Instead of resetting to that last, good commit - let's call it 'target' - you could add a branch there and switch to it, cherry-pick the new, good commits to that branch, then reset the original branch - let's say it's master - to there. I.e. `git checkout -b newbranch <target hash>`, then `git cherry-pick <good commit>` for each new, good commit, then `git checkout master`, and `git reset --hard newbranch`, then `git branch -d newbranch`.

Comment: This seems to have worked with the `git push master origin --force` command to follow it all up :)  Thanks!